# How to make separator (Single Line) transparent in Tableview?

Tags: uitableview, transparent, separator

I have used table view in my application, and within that I have used the single line separator given by tableview.
How can I make a transparent separator in a tableview?

If anybody has any ideas/code snippets/useful links, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

it's very simple
in your viewdidload use this

[yourTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: @TheJeff your background color will be displayed then

Comment: That's what I would have guessed too, but my background is black for the Table View and for the View that it is contained in. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: try setting tint color on UITableView instance

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is still looking for solution with 'transparent' separator of any height:

Inside custom UITableViewCell:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let mutablePath = CGMutablePath()
    mutablePath.addRect(self.bounds)
    // frame for your separator
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 55, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: 5)
    mutablePath.addRect(frame)
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = mutablePath
    mask.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd
    self.layer.mask = mask
    if !(self.superview?.isKind(of: UITableView.self) ?? false) {
      self.superview?.layer.mask = mask
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use 
`tableView.separatorColor = .clear`